# How to copy and paste values from an input type="button"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, input, greasemonkey

I have to copy and paste the values of input type="button" (ie value="1.25", value="3.50") from a lot of pages. Is it possible using jquery or greasemonkey?

```
<td>
    <input type="button" onmouseout="btnGiocataOut(this)" onmouseover="btnGiocataOver(this)" onclick="aggiungiScommessa(6659, 12, 22, 1, 125)" value="1.25" class="ris">
</td>
<td class="valore" colspan="1">Over</td>
<td>
    <input type="button" onmouseout="btnGiocataOut(this)" onmouseover="btnGiocataOver(this)" onclick="aggiungiScommessa(6659, 12, 22, 2, 350)" value="3.50" class="ris">
</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

http://www.learningjquery.com/2006/12/jquerify-bookmarklet

JQuery bookmarklet - and then in firebug console:

```
$("input[type='button']").each(function() { console.log($(this).val()); });
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you want to grab button values automatically, without futzing with Firebug on every page, Greasemonkey can do that.

Here's a script that should get you started.  Be sure to adjust the `@include` statements to match your target sites.

```
//
// ==UserScript==
// @name            Button value grabber
// @namespace       Gambling
// @description     Grabs button values.
// @include         *
// @require         http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js
// ==/UserScript==
//

$(document).ready (Greasemonkey_main);

function Greasemonkey_main ()
{
    /*--- Create a container div and area for the values.  It will be styled and
        postioned with CSS.
    */
    $("body").append
    (
          '<div id="GM_PopUpDiv">'
        +   '<h3>Button Values on this page:</h3>'
        +   '<form id="GM_ContForm"><textarea id="GM_BtnValues"><\/textarea><\/form>'
        + '<\/div>'
    );

    //--- Make it almost invisible when not moused over.
    $('#GM_PopUpDiv').hover
    (
        function () { $(this).stop (true, false).fadeTo (50, 1); },
        function () { $(this).stop (true, false).fadeTo (900, 0.15); }
    );

    /*--- Copy the button values.   Fine-tune the selector to taste.
        For example, input.ris[type='button']
    */
    var NumRows = 0;
    var BtnVals = $("input[type='button']").map (function(J) {
                    NumRows = J;
                    return this.value;
                } ).get ().join ('\n')
                ;

    /*--- Paste the values into the textarea and adjust the height to the data
        (within the min/max set by CSS, below).
    */
    $("#GM_BtnValues").text (BtnVals). css ('height', NumRows + 4 + 'em');
}


//--- This is just CSS to make the new stuff look "purty".
GM_addStyle
(
   '#GM_PopUpDiv                                                    \
    {                                                               \
        font-size:              16px;                               \
        background:             wheat;                              \
        border:                 3px double #999999;                 \
        margin:                 5px;                                \
                                                                    \
        min-height:             100px;                              \
        min-width:              400px;                              \
        padding:                5px 20px;                           \
                                                                    \
        opacity:                0.15;                               \
        z-index:                1222;                               \
        position:               fixed;                              \
        top:                    0px;                                \
        left:                   0px;                                \
    }                                                               \
    #GM_PopUpDiv textarea                                           \
    {                                                               \
        font-size:              16px;                               \
        min-height:             6em;                                \
        max-height:             32em;                               \
        width:                  100%;                               \
        padding:                8px;                                \
        word-wrap:              normal;                             \
    }                                                               \
    #GM_PopUpDiv h3                                                 \
    {                                                               \
        font-size:              16px;                               \
        text-align:             left;                               \
        margin:                 0px;                                \
    }                                                               \
   '
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I use Firebug and jQuery in one-off situations like this. I load jQuery dynamically if necessary: `$('<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js" />').appendTo(document.body);`. That goes in the Firebug console. Then I would use something like `$('input').each(function() { console.log($(this).val()); });`, and it would print out a list that I could easily copy. I would repet these steps for every page.